# random number generator monkey test diehard

Tags: testing, random, monkey

I have a question about Diehard Testtool. My Random Number Generator doesn't passed monkey test (DNA Test).  One p-value was 0. Is this critical? How can I interpret the result?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can never be sure with random number generators. If one odd test gives a p value in one of the bitstreams as 0 or nearly 0 then it might not be a cause of worry but if u get most p values as 0 and till six decimal places then it needs further testing.